# Urban Airship not showing alert within the app

Tags: ios, push, uialertview, urbanairship.com

I'm migrating from parse.com to urban airship, I'm almost done and everything is working, but one thing. When my app it's being open, and a push notification is sent the alert view **IS NOT** being displayed. If I put the app on the **background** or **close** the app I **successfully** **receive** the **notification**.

I have try different things to make it work, I try adding:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    UAirship.push().appRegisteredForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken(deviceToken)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    UAirship.push().appRegisteredUserNotificationSettings()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    UAirship.push().appReceivedRemoteNotification(userInfo, applicationState: application.applicationState)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    UAirship.push().appReceivedRemoteNotification(userInfo,
        applicationState:application.applicationState,
        fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    UAirship.push().appReceivedActionWithIdentifier(identifier!,
        notification: userInfo,
        applicationState: application.applicationState,
        completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    UAirship.push().appReceivedActionWithIdentifier(identifier!,
        notification: userInfo,
        responseInfo: responseInfo,
        applicationState: application.applicationState,
        completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

And changing the **UAConfig** to **automatic** **setup** **disabled**:

```
        let config: UAConfig = UAConfig.defaultConfig()
    config.automaticSetupEnabled = false
    UAirship.takeOff(config)
```

I have also added to my **AppDelegate** this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UAPushNotificationDelegate {
```

And **putting** **this**:

```
        UAirship.push().userNotificationTypes = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    UAirship.push().pushNotificationDelegate = self
```

But **nothing** **worked**, I'm really frustrated with this because I can't make it work and for me, the Urban Airship documentation, it is not clear about this matter.

If I'm not mistaken, it should work by default, without doing all this, but it does not.

I hope someone can help me, here is my complete code without all the modifications:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    // Populate AirshipConfig.plist with your app's info from
    // https://go.urbanairship.com
    // or set runtime properties here.
    let config: UAConfig = UAConfig.defaultConfig()
    UAirship.takeOff(config)

    UAirship.push().userPushNotificationsEnabled = true

    // Clear badge
    UAirship.push().resetBadge()

    return true
}[...]}
```

I'm using Swift 2, XCode 7.2.1 and iOS8, and Urban AirShip 6.4.x

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to trigger an alert display when a foreground notification is received you will need to implement the [UAPushNotificationDelegate](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Protocols/UAPushNotificationDelegate.html) and handle the alert there. Presenting an alert when a foreground notification is received is not a default behavior in the Urban Airship SDK.

**Push notification delegate**

Create a class that that implements UAPushNotificationDelegate and and includes the optional receivedForegroundNotification method or the displayNotificationAlert method.

```
class PushNotificationDelegate : NSObject, UAPushNotificationDelegate {

    func receivedForegroundNotification(notification: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)) {
        // Called when the app receives a foreground notification. Includes the notification dictionary.

        // Call the completion handler
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
    }

    func displayNotificationAlert(alertMessage: String) {
       // Called when an alert notification is received in the foreground. Includes a simple string to be displayed as an alert.
    }


}
```

**Set delegate**

```
UAirship.push().pushNotificationDelegate = customPushDelegate
```

You can review Urban Airship's [documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#handling-notifications) for the push notification delegate.

Comment: I'm missing something else, because it's still not working :/

Comment: How are you configuring the push notification delegate? It must be set after  `UAirship.takeOff(config)`.

Comment: It's like that. I'm receiving the push on my iPhone, but the alert is not being displayed. Do I have to create an alert inside those methods?

Comment: That's right. You'll need to create the alert view in either the receivedForegroundNotification or the displayNotificationAlert method.

Comment: And what if I want to add a banner instead of an alert?